# Azure MarsAgent Upgrade Failed

Tags: azure, backup

I have an issue, I am trying to upgrade the MarsAgent (Azure agent) on a Windows 7 PC. When I try to update it I get the error:

`"An unexpected error occurred during the installation. For more details check the setup error logs.(Error ID: 116)"`.

You then press OK on that error and I am then presented with

```
"Error starting the Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent Setup Wizard"
```

Can you please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error whet tried to installed MarsAgent on win2016 server. I tried many articles but no luck. When I selected installed with window updates it shown me error for window update service. so I checked Windows update service found it was in disabled state, hence I set startup type automatic and started service then tried. Issue resolved no error found.